# How do a stop this procedure from poping out?

Tags: python

I'm doing this coffee shop in python and I want to let the costumer go back to choosing the size, but once it does and it goes back to the drink type, get_drink_type comes out two times. How can I make it so it only comes up once?
I have already tried putting a for loop before, but it didn't actually stop the problem.

```
def print_message():
  print('''I'm sorry, I did not understand your selection. Please enter the corresponding letter for your response.''')


def get_size():
  res = input('What size drink can I get for you? \n[a] Small \n[b] Medium \n[c] Large \n> ')
  redo = get_drink_type()
  if res == 'a':
    if redo == 'd':
      get_drink_type()
    return 'small'
  elif res == 'b':
    if redo == 'd':
      get_drink_type()
    return 'medium'
  elif res == 'c':
    if redo == 'd':
      get_drink_type()
    return 'large'
  else:
    print_message()
    return get_size()

def get_drink_type():
  kind = input('What type of drink would you like? \n[a] Brewed Coffee \n[b] Mocha \n[c] Latte \n[d] Return to the size \n> ')
  if kind == 'a':
    return 'brewed coffee'
  elif kind == 'b':
    return 'mocha'
  elif kind == 'c':
    return order_latte()
  elif kind == 'd':
    return get_size()
  else:
    print_message()
    return get_drink_type()

def order_latte():
  latte = input('And what kind of milk for your latte? \n[a] 2% milk \n[b] Non-fat milk \n[c] Soy milk \n> ')
  if latte == 'a':
    return 'latte'
  elif latte == 'b':
    return 'non-fat latte'
  elif latte == 'c':
    return 'soy latte'
  else:
    print_message()
    return order_latte()
    
def get_desert():
  desert = input('Would you like an extra dessert with your coffee? \n[a] 5 cookies \n[b] An icecream \n[c] A brownie \n[d] No, thank you \n>')
  if desert == 'a':
    return 'cookies'
  elif desert == 'b':
    return get_icecream_flavour()
  elif desert == 'c':
    return get_brownie()
  elif desert == 'd':
    return 'nothing'
  else:
    print_message()
    return get_desert()

def get_brownie():
  brownie = input('Do you want ice cream with your brownie? \n[a] Yes  \n[b] No \n>')
  if brownie =='a':
    return get_icecream_brownie()
  elif brownie == 'b':
    return 'brownie with no ice cream'
  else:
    print_message()
    return get_brownie()

def get_icecream_brownie():
  flavour = input('What flavour would you like your ice cream to be? \n[a] Vanilla \n[b] Chocolate \n[c] Strawberry \n>')
  if flavour == 'a':
    return 'brownie with a vanilla ice cream'
  elif flavour == 'b':
    return 'brownie with a chocolate ice cream'
  elif flavour == 'c':
    return 'brownie with a strawberry ice cream'
  else:
    print_message()
    return get_icecream_brownie()

def get_icecream_flavour():
  flavour = input('What flavour would you like your ice cream to be? \n[a] Vanilla \n[b] Chocolate \n[c] Strawberry \n>')
  if flavour == 'a':
    return 'vanilla ice cream'
  elif flavour == 'b':
    return 'chocolate ice cream'
  elif flavour == 'c':
    return 'strawberry ice cream'
  else:
    print_message()
    return get_icecream_flavour()

# Define your functions
def coffee_bot():
  print('''Welcome to the cafe!''')
  name = input('Can I get you name pls? \n> ')
  size = get_size()
  if size == 'small':
    a = 1.00
  elif size == 'medium':
    a = 1.20
  else:
    a = 1.50
  
  drink_type = get_drink_type()
  if drink_type == 'brewed coffee':
    b = 1.50
  elif drink_type == 'mocha':
    b = 1.20
  elif drink_type == 'latte':
    b = 1.40
  elif drink_type == 'non-fat latte':
    b = 1.80
  elif drink_type == 'soy latte':
    b = 2.00

  dessert = get_desert()
  if dessert == 'cookies':
    c = 1.20
  elif dessert == 'vanilla ice cream':
    c = 1.40
  elif dessert == 'chocolate ice cream':
    c = 1.40
  elif dessert == 'strawberry ice cream':
    c = 1.40
  elif dessert == 'nothing':
    c = 0.0
  elif dessert == 'brownie with no ice cream':
    c = 4.00
  else:
    c = 5.40

  d = format(a + b + c, '.2f')
  d = str(d)
  if dessert == 'nothing':
    first_message = '''Alright, that's a ''' + size +' '+ drink_type + ' wtih no dessert and a total price of ' + d + '€'
    print(first_message)
    print ('''Thanks, ''' +name+'''! Your order will be ready shortly.''')
  elif dessert == 'cookies':
    first_message = '''Alright, that's a ''' + size +' '+ drink_type + ' plus 5 ' + dessert + ' with a total price of ' + d + '€'
    print(first_message)
    print ('''Thanks, ''' +name+'''! Your order will be ready shortly.''')
  else:
    first_message = '''Alright, that's a ''' + size +' '+ drink_type + ' plus a ' + dessert + ' with a total price of ' + d + '€'
    print(first_message)
    print ('''Thanks, ''' +name+'''! Your order will be ready shortly.''')
coffee_bot()
```

Comment: Stop using recursion. That will fix it

Comment: Welcome Maxor, please reduce your code to the absolute minimum to reproduce your problem. In most cases 4-5 lines of code are sufficient. That helps you to better understand the problem and also the community: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example